# How to split data in txt file to Excel?

Tags: c#, excel

I have hundreds of .txt files with error logs like the ones below. My goal is to create a report on Excel containing the name, date, number of repetitions and error content of each error in the file by selecting the file I want (more than one file can be selected). How can I do this using C#?

Example data (we must assume that this data is in a txt file and consists of thousands of lines):

```
2023-11-14 00:00:00,123 |1|ERROR||Ex: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
2023-11-14 00:00:00,546 |2|ERROR|Ex: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
2023-11-14 00:00:00,624 |1|ERROR|Ex: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
2023-11-14 00:00:00,555 |111|ERROR|||ExCode: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
2023-11-14 00:00:00,666 |111|ERROR|ExCode: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
156156156 xyz Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
2023-11-14 01:00:00,199 |1|ERROR|Ex: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
2023-11-14 01:00:00,266 |2|ERROR|Ex: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
```

I tried something with C# like below. But I can not split data. How can I do it ?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            String line;
            List<string> sList = new List<string>();
            try
            {
                //Pass the file path and file name to the StreamReader constructor
                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("deneme.txt");
                //Read the first line of text
                line = sr.ReadLine();
                //Continue to read until you reach end of file
                while (line != null)
                {
                    string[] pieces = line.Split('|');
                    //write the line to console window
                    //Console.WriteLine(line);
                    for (int i = 0; i < line.Length; i++)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(pieces[i]);
                    }
                   
                    //Read the next line
                    line = sr.ReadLine();
                }
                //close the file
                sr.Close();
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + e.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Executing finally block.");
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you see that your code produces the error: "Index was outside the bounds of the array." ?  Try iterating over `pieces` instead of `line`: `for (int i = 0; i < pieces.Length; i++)`, since `pieces` is your array that's been split. `line` is just the un-split line of text.

Comment: In a line of log, sometime there are the characters '|' more than one. Parse based on the "|" character with remove empty entries. Like this: String[] words = line.Split(new String[] { "|" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries); –

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. First install `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel`

   From `VS2022` > `Tools` > `Nuget Package Manager` > `Package Manager Console` >
   then type
   `NuGet\Install-Package Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel -Version 15.0.4795.1001` > then enter.
2. Try C# code as follows:

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Application = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application;

namespace LogParsing
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                // create excel
                Application logApp = new Application();
                if (logApp == null)
                {
                    return;
                }

                // collect all log files
                String[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"d:\mylog", "*.txt");
                if (files == null || files.Length == 0)
                {
                    return;
                }

                foreach (String file in files)
                {
                    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(file))
                    {
                        // next file
                        continue;
                    }

                    // read file content
                    String[] lines = File.ReadLines(file).ToArray();
                    if (lines == null)
                    {
                        // next line
                        continue;
                    }

                    // create workbook
                    Workbook logWorkbook = logApp.Workbooks.Add();
                    if (logWorkbook == null)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }

                    // create worksheet
                    Worksheet logWorksheet = (Worksheet)logWorkbook.Sheets.Add();
                    logWorksheet.Name = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file);
                    if (logWorksheet == null)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }

                    int row = 1;
                    foreach (String line in lines)
                    {
                        if (line == null)
                        {
                            continue;
                        }

                        // parsing words with remove empty data
                        String[] words = line.Split(new String[] { "|" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

                        if (words == null || words.Length == 0)
                        {
                            // next when words is empty
                            continue;
                        }
                        if (words.Length == 4)
                        {
                            // fill worksheet
                            for (int i = 0; i < words.Length; i++)
                            {
                                String word = words[i];
                                logWorksheet.Cells[row, 1 + i] = word;
                            }

                            // next row
                            ++row;
                        }
                    }

                    // save worksheet
                    logApp.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs(Path.GetDirectoryName(file) + "/" + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file) + ".xls", XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal);

                    // close worksheet
                    logWorkbook.Close();
                }
                logApp.Quit();

                MessageBox.Show("Succes");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.StackTrace);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

3. Right click `Your Solution` > select `Sync Namespaces` to update the namespaces automatically (without you having to update it manually).
4. Run your `Program`.

Result:

[image]

Answer (score -2):

Your code is producing the error: ["Index was outside the bounds of the array."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20940979/what-is-an-indexoutofrangeexception-argumentoutofrangeexception-and-how-do-i-f) and it's producing that error because you're using the length of `line` to determine the index to use in `'pieces`. That's going to give you an invalid index. The length of `line` is the length of the string before you've split it into an array and that value has no relationship to the indexes of `pieces`.

You can see the difference:

```
Console.WriteLine(line.Length);
Console.WriteLine(pieces.Length);
```

In the example below, `line.Length` is 94 and `pieces.Length` is 5.

Your problem is that you're attempting to iterate over `pieces` using the length of `line`. You need to use the length of `pieces` to make sure you don't exceed the index bounds in your loop.

```
var line = "2023-11-14 00:00:00,123 |1|ERROR||Ex: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.";

string[] pieces = line.Split('|');

for (int i = 0; i < pieces.Length; i++)
{
     Console.WriteLine(pieces[i]);
}
```

Your code also doesn't interate over all lines in the file. It only reads one line.  To interate over all lines:

```
using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(("deneme.txt"))
{
     var line = String.Empty;
     //this will loop over each line in the file
     while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
     {
         //split your line into an array
         string[] pieces = line.Split('|');

         //iternate over the array
         for (int i = 0; i < pieces.Length; i++)
         {
              Console.WriteLine(pieces[i]);
         }   
     }
```

}

Note: `StreamReader` implements iDisposable, so wrap it with `using`
see here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/using?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Also, my answer is addressing the problems in the code you provided. You don't show or explain whether you have issues writing the split lines to Excel so I'm assuming that's not part of your problem.

Comment: But I want to read txt file with C#. Each txt file include hundreds of lines. How can I implement the code on my source code ?

Comment: @MehmetAliKarabulut I understand that, but I'm giving you an example of what happens on each line you read.  Replace `for (int i = 0; i < line.Length; i++)` with `for (int i = 0; i < pieces.Length; i++)` in your code.

Comment: @MehmetAliKarabulut also, it looks like you're only reading one line of your file in your code. I'll update my answer to show how to iterate over all lines in your file.

Comment: @MehmetAliKarabulut - I've updated it.